# How to ensure type safety with Scala's Refined library when using the same predicate for refinement

Tags: scala, newtype, refinement-type, refined

I am new to scala and the refined library but I am trying to create two refined types based on UUIDs.

In order to do so, I did this (Note: Uuid in this case comes from eu.timepit.refined.string.Uuid):

```
type UuidPredicate = Uuid

type UuidA = String Refined UuidPredicate
type UuidB = String Refined UuidPredicate
```

However, it appears as though this only creates aliases, and therefore there is no type safety.

So if I had a constructor like `Product(a UuidA, b UuidB)`
and proceeded to do something like this:

```
val myUuid: UuidA = "9f9ef0c6-b6f8-11ea-b3de-0242ac130004"
val Product = Product(myUuid, myUuid)
```

It would compile and run properly. Is there anyway to ensure this is not the case? If a variable is created as one type, how can I make it so it only be used as that particular refined type, even though the types are fundamentally the same?

Comment: You want a [**newtype**](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype) not sure how well both libraries play together. BTW, quick disclaimer all this is pretty advanced stuff, if you are new to the language you may suffer a bit.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `newtype` introduces macro annotation (expanded earlier, case class is replaced with a type and object) and `refined` introduces implicit def macros (expanded later, conversions `String => String Refined ...`) so there shouldn't be problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to introduce different data types

```
case class UuidA(value: String Refined UuidPredicate)
case class UuidB(value: String Refined UuidPredicate)
```

You can't make `UuidA`, `UuidB` extend `AnyVal` because `Refined` already extends `AnyVal` and Scala doesn't allow nested value classes.

If you prefer to avoid runtime overhead of wrapping with `UuidA`, `UuidB` you can try `@newtype` as **@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez** adviced

```
import io.estatico.newtype.macros.newtype

@newtype case class UuidA(value: String Refined UuidPredicate)
@newtype case class UuidB(value: String Refined UuidPredicate)
```

Or try to add more tags

```
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined
import eu.timepit.refined.string.Uuid
import eu.timepit.refined.auto._
import shapeless.tag
import shapeless.tag.@@

type UuidPredicate = Uuid
type UuidString = Refined[String, UuidPredicate]
type TagA
type TagB
type UuidA = UuidString @@ TagA
type UuidB = UuidString @@ TagB

case class Product(a: UuidA, b: UuidB)
val myUuid: UuidA = tag[TagA][UuidString]("9f9ef0c6-b6f8-11ea-b3de-0242ac130004")
//  val product = Product(myUuid, myUuid) // doesn't compile
val myUuid1: UuidB = tag[TagB][UuidString]("9f9ef0c6-b6f8-11ea-b3de-0242ac130004")
val product1 = Product(myUuid, myUuid1) // compiles
```